# Change color of preview expressions in Auctex

Tags: auctex, colors, images

In the customize group "Preview Appearance", I click on "Preview Face" and set "Foreground" to "red". To the right, I see the word "sample" displayed in red. Then I select "Save for Future Sessions." But when I generate previews in my tex file, they are white instead of red.

How can I change the color of the preview images?

Comment: I haven't used AucTeX in years ... but, is it possible for you to place your cursor on a character containing the face at issue and, if so, type `C-u C-x =` and read the `*Help*` buffer that pops up to see what faces are there.  Then, you can type `M-x customize-face` and enter the face name and proceed from there in terms of whether to set the face for this session only, or as to future sessions as well ....

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the preview is a png image that cannot be manipulated like normal emacs text.

Comment: This hasn‘t been fixed yet. And I have the same problem with underlines and overlines btw. Or did you come up with another solution?